# Angular2 Module: How can i import a service from another module

Tags: angular, angular2-modules, angular2-providers

```ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { ClinicFacilityService } from './apiClient.module';


@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    DailyScheduleComponent,
  ],
  providers: [
    ClinicFacilityService
  ],
  exports: [
    DailyScheduleComponent
  ],
})
export class ClinicDashboardModule {
}
```

I need to import `ClinicFacilityService` that is declared in another module (`apiClient.module`)

Is this even possible, if not why is not possible. At the moment i am importing `ClinicFacilityService` like this:

```ts
import { ClinicFacilityService } from './api-client-service/clinic-facility.service';
```

Comment: This is kinda old post but for the sake of others, I find this [article](https://medium.com/@michelestieven/organizing-angular-applications-f0510761d65a) very comprehensive and fully answers this question. Hint: see **Importing services** section of that article.

Comment: The answer to this depends on how the service is injected in the service file itself

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Adding the module to imports should do

```ts
import { ApiClientModule } from './apiClient.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ApiClientModule,
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    DailyScheduleComponent,
  ],
  exports: [
    DailyScheduleComponent
  ],
})
export class ClinicDashboardModule {
}
```

otherwise import the file that contains the service class

```ts
import { ClinicFacilityService } from './clinic-facility.service';
```

There is a clear distinction between `@NgModule()` `imports` and TypeScript imports.

If you need to use the class name (`ClinicFacilityService`) then a TypeScript import of that class is required. This is entirely unrelated to `@NgModule()`

```ts
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    ClinicFacilityService
  ],
```

If the `@NgModule()` import is required, then the class name of the module class (`ApiClientModule`) requires a TypeScript import because the module needs to be passed.

```ts
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ApiClientModule,
  ],
```

- TypeScript imports are to to uniquely identify a class.
- NgModule imports are to define that a module depends on another module.

Comment: Glad to hear :)

Comment: Very helpful information, re: difference between Angular import and TypeScript import

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I am not clear here. Are you saying, you can basically keep the service file as it is in feature module and still use it in the importing module?

Comment: I think it would be best if you would create a new question where you explain what you try to accomplish, what you tried, and what exactly didn't work as you expected.