# Angular modules and services

Tags: angular

Given two modules, `ModuleA` and `ModuleB`, in `ModuleA` we want to use `ServiceB` from `ModuleB`. What should be done so the following code is functional?

```
@NgModule({
        imports: [],
        providers: [ServiceA],
        declarations: [ComponentA],
        bootstrap: [ComponentA]
        )
}
export class ModuleA {}
@NgModule({
        imports: [],
        providers: [ServiceB],
        declarations: [ComponentB],
        bootstrap: [ComponentB]
        )
}
export class ModuleB {}
```

Comment: check out [import service from another module in angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40396070/angular2-module-how-can-i-import-a-service-from-another-module)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to export the service from ModuleB and add the ModubleB under imports of the ModubleA.

**Module A:**

```
@NgModule({
imports:        [ModubleB],
providers:  [ ServiceA ],
declarations:   [ ComponentA ],
bootstrap:      [ ComponentA ]
)}
```

**`ModuleB`**

```
export class ModuleB { }
@NgModule({
imports:        [ ],
providers:  [ ServiceB ],
declarations:   [ ComponentB ],
bootstrap:      [ ComponentB ]
exports : [ServiceB]
)}
```