# Adding HttpClientModule to Angular library throws `NullInjectorError: No provider for Injector`

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm developing a Angular library. I've setup the library like this:

`ng new mylibrary --create-application false`
`ng g library mylib`

Now, I can `ng build` this and create an app that uses it, like this:

`ng new myapp`
`npm install ../mylibrary/dist/mylib`
and add the `MylibModule` to the `imports` of my `app.module.ts`

This works fine, by default the library has a component that I can use. There also is a dependency injected service in the library.. also works fine.

Now I want to extend my library with http calls, so I add the `HttpClientModule` to the import of my library module, and the HttpClient to the constructor of my service. I rebuild the lib with `ng build` and on the app I re-run `npm install`.. and run with `ng serve` and now my app throws:

`StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[HttpHandler -> Injector]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for Injector!`

I guess I somehow have to tell the library to use the injected HttpClient from the app, but how?

**EDIT**
Adding repo: https://github.com/floreseken/NgLibDI

Comment: Have you added HttpClientModule to your list of imports in your main module?

Comment: Yes, does not help

Comment: Does your library contain any injectable services? If so in your app you would need to add these under providers. It's hard to see what the problem could be as there's no code to view.

Comment: Tried that. Same error. I just added a repo which shows the behaviour.

Comment: Btw.. the library has a injectable service which works fine without adding it as provider.. as long as I don't add the HttpClientModule

Comment: Take a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40396070/angular2-module-how-can-i-import-a-service-from-another-module). Try exporting MylibService from your library then import it into your app and add it as a provider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because of the module linking. If you use "ng server --aot", you will not face the issue. Can you remove the links and copy the module directly to node_modules

open the C:\Git\NgLibDI\myapp\node_modules and delete the "mylib" link and manually copy myLib from the Dist to the node_modules of the myapp

Comment: check. I also found out that setting "preserveSymlinks": true, in the angular.json file fixes it.. that is the nicest solution I guess.